# Should "user-interface" be a tag synonym for "gui-construction"

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are presently 122 questions tagged [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction) and only 10 tagged [user-interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface).  Should these tags be merged and made synonymous?  If so which should be the master?  User-interface seems broader perhaps?

Comment: I'm leaning towards a merge, plus a rename into [tag:user-interfaces].

Comment: User-interface is the more general category. It can also refer to external controllers as possible in Manipulate and acoustic and tactile feedback. The G in GUI restricts the definition to on-screen interfaces.

Comment: @Sjoerd That was my perception.  Do you feel there is risk of diluting the meaning too much?

Comment: For now, I believe user interface questions mostly concern graphical interfaces. This may change in the future though (I remember having written about interfacing with the WII balance board a couple of years ago), and a distinction may be needed then. Having to re-tag all questions at that time may be a pain. So, I see three alternatives: 1) using User-interface as a main tag and adding relevant sub tags (GUI, tactile, controllers) or 2) not using user-interfaces and directly tag the subtype of UI or 3) if traffic is low, use user-interface as synonym and master.

Comment: I see some examples of touch related functions for tablet based inputs emerging in V10, so I expect this aspect will be fleshed out more in future updates. This will increase the need for separate tags.

Comment: I'm not really in favor of one option or another, but if I had to choose right now I'd pick 1).

Comment: related: [1265](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1265/5478)

Answer (score 5):

This is a difficult issue because some people are interpreting [user-interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) as a synonym for [front-end](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end). For example, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61053/3066). Those who are doing so are being quite reasonable since [user-interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) has no tag wiki excerpt to guide them.

I also note that there is a tag, [gui-elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-elements) (15 uses), which seems a more likely candidate for being made a synonym for [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction)